# Creating a linked-list of variable length

Tags: linked-list, common-lisp

I have a list of `((a)(b)(f(x)))`. What i would like to get is a linked list structure of`((a)(b)(f(x1))(a)(b)(f(x2))(a)(b)(f(x3))))`. That is, repeatively appending the list the on the basis of requirement of the user and the value of the variable is chaning so that its value will be unique from each other. How can i implement it in LISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
? (let ((list '((a) (b) (f (x))))
        (n 3))
    (flet ((copier (l n)
             (setf l (copy-tree l))
             (let ((sym (first (second (third l)))))
               (setf (first (second (third l)))
                     (intern (format nil "~a~a"
                                     (symbol-name sym)
                                     n))))
             l))
      (loop for i from 1 upto n
        nconc (copier list i))))

((A) (B) (F (X1)) (A) (B) (F (X2)) (A) (B) (F (X3)))
```

Comment: ... and suddenly my solution looks quite elegant.

Comment: @larsmans: a) take the list as input. b) don't COLLECT, but APPEND... - check the nesting of your result list.

Comment: Ah, right. I misunderstood the question. (The OP's result list has unbalanced parentheses, btw.)

Comment: @larsmans: but you could have fixed your code. That would have been not so difficult...

Comment: my Lisp is rusty and you already gave the answer, so I didn't bother. +1, btw.